# Transactions in REST?

Tags: rest

I'm wondering how you'd implement the following use-case in REST. Is it even possible to do without compromising the conceptual model?

Read or update multiple resources within the scope of a single transaction. For example, transfer $100 from Bob's bank account into John's account.

As far as I can tell, the only way to implement this is by cheating. You could POST to the resource associated with either John or Bob and carry out the entire operation using a single transaction. As far as I'm concerned this breaks the REST architecture because you're essentially tunneling an RPC call through POST instead of really operating on individual resources.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Consider a RESTful shopping basket scenario.  The shopping basket is conceptually your transaction wrapper.  In the same way that you can add multiple items to a shopping basket  and then submit that basket to process the order, you can add Bob's account entry to the transaction wrapper and then Bill's account entry to the wrapper.   When all the pieces are in place then you can POST/PUT the transaction wrapper with all the component pieces.

Comment: I get the shopping basket example, but how when you generalize this it doesn't sound RESTful at all (you're not operating on resources). There is no realistic bank-related resource to wrap John and Bob.

Good answer though! I feel like you're definitely moving in the right direction.

Comment: Why would TransferMoneyTransaction not be a viable banking resource?

Comment: I thought a resource was supposed to be a real-life object, not a service (i.e. method invocation). If you're able to make up resources that mimic services then how is REST any different from RPC?

Comment: If your ensure that your endpoints refer to nouns then it is usually intuitive what the standard GET, PUT, POST, DELETE verbs will do to that noun.  RPC  allows endpoints to be verbs themselves and therefore they can conflict with the HTTP verbs and the intent becomes confusing.

Comment: e.g. What happens if you do an HTTP DELETE on the endpoint UpdateXYZ ?   Does it delete XYZ?  Does it delete the Update or does it just do an Update and ignore the HTTP verb delete.  By keeping verbs out of the endpoint you remove the confusion.

Comment: And what about transactions across multiple services? and what about when you want to do a set of 'unrelated' changes that the service exposes no implicit transaction container.. plus, why have a specific transaction type when we're moved to general purpose transactions that are completely unrelated to your actual data changes. Transactions might not match restful, but it seems like transactions should be layered ontop, unrelated to the rest calls apart from the fact the request headers would contain a transaction reference.

Comment: @meandmycode  Database transactions should be layered behind a REST interface.  Alternately you can expose a business transactions (not a database transaction) as a resource in itself and then you need to take compensating action in case of failure.

Comment: this isnt what i mean.. scenario: i want to add an album to my catalog, and an artist to my artists catalog (with a link from album to artist). i want to have this all or nothing, and i dont want to compensate, the operation should feel atomic.

Comment: Put your scenario as a separate question and I'll answer it there.  Comments are a pain for discussing this.  Also, you will get input from others too.

Comment: this is so wrong! shopping baskets are not a transaction. if you require another step to submit it, then technically the shopping basket can change after you have added items and before you submit

Answer (score 64):

There are a few important cases that aren't answered by this question, which I think is too bad, because it has a high ranking on Google for the search terms :-)

Specifically, a nice propertly would be: If you POST twice (because some cache hiccupped in the intermediate) you should not transfer the amount twice.

To get to this, you create a transaction as an object. This could contain all the data you know already, and put the transaction in a pending state.

```
POST /transfer/txn
{"source":"john's account", "destination":"bob's account", "amount":10}

{"id":"/transfer/txn/12345", "state":"pending", "source":...}
```

Once you have this transaction, you can commit it, something like:

```
PUT /transfer/txn/12345
{"id":"/transfer/txn/12345", "state":"committed", ...}

{"id":"/transfer/txn/12345", "state":"committed", ...}
```

Note that multiple puts don't matter at this point; even a GET on the txn would return the current state. Specifically, the second PUT would detect that the first was already in the appropriate state, and just return it -- or, if you try to put it into the "rolledback" state after it's already in "committed" state, you would get an error, and the actual committed transaction back.

As long as you talk to a single database, or a database with an integrated transaction monitor, this mechanism will actually work just fine. You might additionally introduce time-outs for transactions, which you could even express using Expires headers if you wanted to.

Comment: Interesting discussion! I'd like to add that the initial post must be performed in one step. It cannot be added to later (then we're in shopping-cart territory and shopping carts have many checks and balances to prevent them from causing harm to the end user, even legislation, bank transfers does not)...

Answer (score 35):

In REST terms, resources are nouns that can be acted on with CRUD (create/read/update/delete) verbs. Since there is no "transfer money" verb, we need to define a "transaction" resource that can be acted upon with CRUD. Here's an example in HTTP+POX. First step is to **CREATE** (HTTP POST method) a new **empty** transaction:

```
POST /transaction
```

This returns a transaction ID, e.g. "1234" and according URL "/transaction/1234". Note that firing this POST multiple times will not create the same transaction with multiple IDs and also avoids introduction of a "pending" state. Also, POST can't always be idempotent (a REST requirement), so it's generally good practice to minimize data in POSTs.

You could leave the generation of a transaction ID up to the client. In this case, you would POST /transaction/1234 to create transaction "1234" and the server would return an error if it already existed. In the error response, the server could return a currently unused ID with an appropriate URL. It's not a good idea to query the server for a new ID with a GET method, since GET should never alter server state, and creating/reserving a new ID would alter server state.

Next up, we **UPDATE** (PUT HTTP method) the transaction with all data, implicitly committing it:

```
PUT /transaction/1234
<transaction>
  <from>/account/john</from>
  <to>/account/bob</to>
  <amount>100</amount>
</transaction>
```

If a transaction with ID "1234" has been PUT before, the server gives an error response, otherwise an OK response and a URL to view the completed transaction.

NB: in /account/john , "john" should really be John's unique account number.

Comment: Equating REST with CRUD is a serious mistake. POST does not have to mean CREATE.

Comment: Serious mistake?  I know there are differences between PUT and POST, but there is a loose mapping to CRUD.  "Seriously"?

Comment: Yes, seriously. CRUD is a way of structuring data storage; REST is a ways of structuring application data flow. You can do CRUD on REST, but you cannot do REST on CRUD. They are not equivalent.

Answer (score 20):

Great question, REST is mostly explained with database-like examples, where something is stored, updated, retrieved, deleted.  There are few examples like this one, where the server is supposed to process the data in some way.  I don't think Roy Fielding included any in his thesis, which was based on http after all.

But he does talk about "representational state transfer" as a state machine, with links moving to the next state.  In this way, the documents (the representations) keep track of the client state, instead of the server having to do it.  In this way, there is no client state, only  state in terms of which link you are on.

I've been thinking about this, and it seems to me reasonable that to get the server to process something for you, when you upload, the server would automatically create related resources, and give you the links to them (in fact, it wouldn't need to automatically create them: it could just tell you the links, and it only create them when and if you follow them - lazy creation). And to also give you links to create *new* related resources - a related resource has the same URI but is longer (adds a suffix). For example:

1. You upload (**POST**) the representation of the concept of a **transaction with all the information.**  This looks just like a RPC call, but it's really creating the "proposed transaction resource".   e.g URI: `/transaction`
   Glitches will cause multiple such resources to be created, each with a different URI.
2. The server's response states the created resource's URI, its representation - this  includes the link (**URI**) to create the related resource of **a new "committed transaction resource".** Other related resources are the link to delete the proposed transaction. These are states in the state-machine, which the client can follow. Logically, these are part of the resource that has been created on the server, beyond the information the client supplied. e.g URIs: `/transaction/1234/proposed`,  `/transaction/1234/committed`
3. You **POST** to the link to **create the "committed transaction resource"**, which creates that resource, changing the state of the server (the balances of the two accounts)**. By its nature, this resource can only be created once, and can't be updated. Therefore, glitches committing many transactions can't occur.
4. You can GET those two resources, to see what their state is. Assuming that a POST can change other resources, the proposal would now be flagged as "committed" (or perhaps, not available at all).

This is similar to how webpages operate, with the final webpage saying "are you sure you want to do this?" That final webpage is itself a representation of the state of the transaction, which includes a link to go to the next state. Not just financial transactions; also (eg) preview then commit on wikipedia.  I guess the distinction in REST is that each stage in the sequence of states has an explicit name (its URI).

In real-life transactions/sales, there are often different physical documents for different stages of a transaction (proposal, purchase order, receipt etc). Even more for buying a house, with settlement etc.

OTOH This feels like playing with semantics to me; I'm uncomfortable with the nominalization of converting verbs into nouns to make it RESTful, "because it uses nouns (URIs) instead of verbs (RPC calls)".  i.e. the noun "committed transaction resource" instead of the verb "commit this transaction". I guess one advantage of nominalization is you can refer to the resource by name, instead of needing to specify it in some other way (such as maintaining session state, so you know what "this" transaction is...)

But the important question is: What are the benefits of this approach?  i.e. In what way is this REST-style better than RPC-style? Is a technique that's great for webpages also helpful for processing information, beyond store/retrieve/update/delete? I think that the key benefit of REST is scalability; one aspect of that is not needing to maintain client state explicitly (but making it implicit in the URI of the resource, and the next states as links in its representation).  In that sense it helps. Perhaps this helps in layering/pipelining too? OTOH only the one user will look at their specific transaction, so there's no advantage in caching it so others can read it, the big win for http.

Comment: Could you please explain how "not needing to keep state on the client" helps scalability? What kind of scalability? Scalability in what sense?

Comment: how does the transaction not store information from the client? /shrug

Answer (score 16):

I've drifted away from this topic for 10 years. Coming back, I can't believe the religion masquerading as science that you wade into when you google rest+reliable. The confusion is mythic.

I would divide this broad question into three:

- Downstream services. Any web service you  develop will have downstream services that you use, and whose transaction syntax you have no choice but to follow. You should try and hide all this from users of your service, and make sure all parts of your operation succeed or fail as a group, then return this result to your users.
- Your services. Clients want unambiguous outcomes to web-service calls, and the usual REST pattern of making POST, PUT or DELETE requests directly on substantive resources strikes me as a poor, and easily improved, way of providing this certainty. If you care about reliability, you need to identify action requests. This id can be a guid created on the client, or a seed value from a relational DB on the server, it doesn't matter. For server generated ID's, use a 'preflight' request-response  to exchange the id of the action. If this request fails or half succeeds, no problem, the client just repeats the request. Unused ids do no harm.
  This is important because it lets all subsequent requests be fully idempotent, in the sense that if they are repeated n times they return the same result and cause nothing further to happen. The server stores all responses against the action id, and if it sees the same request, it replays the same response. A fuller treatment of the pattern is in [this google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1s0joc0yb6kXpXZGfdE9SRutoPQuK9RVa77f92xsXzrM/edit?usp=sharing). The doc suggests an implementation that, I believe(!), broadly follows REST principals. Experts will surely tell me how it violates others. This pattern can be usefully employed for any unsafe call to your web-service, whether or not there are downstream transactions involved.
- Integration of your service into "transactions" controlled by upstream services. In the context of web-services, full ACID transactions are considered as usually not worth the effort, but you can greatly help consumers of your service by providing cancel and/or confirm links in your confirmation response, and thus achieve [transactions by compensation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/compensating-transaction).

Your requirement is a fundamental one. Don't let people tell you your solution is not kosher. Judge their architectures in the light of how well, and how simply, they address your problem.

Answer (score 13):

If you stand back to summarize the discussion here, it's pretty clear that REST is not appropriate for many APIs, particularly when the client-server interaction is inherently stateful, as it is with non-trivial transactions.  Why jump through all the hoops suggested, for client and server both, in order to pedantically follow some principle that doesn't fit the problem?  A better principle is to give the client the easiest, most natural, productive way to compose with the application.

In summary, if you're really doing a lot of transactions (types, not instances) in your application, you really shouldn't be creating a RESTful API.

Comment: Right, but what should be an alternative in case of distributed micro-service architecture?

Comment: @Vitamon definitely gRPC

Answer (score 11):

You'd have to roll your own "transaction id" type of tx management.  So it would be 4 calls:

```
http://service/transaction (some sort of tx request)
http://service/bankaccount/bob (give tx id)
http://service/bankaccount/john (give tx id)
http://service/transaction (request to commit)
```

You'd have to handle the storing of the actions in a DB (if load balanced) or in memory or such, then handling commit, rollback, timeout.

Not really a RESTful day in the park.

Comment: I don't think this is a particularly good illustration. You only need two steps: Create transaction (creates a transaction in "pending" state) and Commit transaction (commits if uncommited, and moves the resource to committed or rolled-back state).

Answer (score 3):

First of all transferring money is nothing that you can not do in a single resource call. The action you want to do is sending money. So you add a money transfer resource to the account of the sender.

```
POST: accounts/alice, new Transfer {target:"BOB", abmount:100, currency:"CHF"}.
```

Done. You do not need to know that this is a transaction that must be atomic etc. You just transfer money aka. send money from A to B.

---

But for the rare cases here a general solution:

If you want to do something very complex involving many resources in a defined context with a lot of restrictions that actually cross the what vs. why barrier (business vs. implementation knowledge) you need to transfer state. Since REST should be stateless you as a client need to transfer the state around.

If you transfer state you need to hide the information inside from the client. The client should not know internal information only needed by the implementation but does not carry information relevant in terms of business. If those information have no business value the state should be encrypted and a metaphor like token, pass or something need to be used.

This way one can pass internal state around and using encryption and signing the system can be still be secure and sound. Finding the right abstraction for the client why he passes around state information is something that is up to the design and architecture.

---

The real solution:

Remember REST is talking HTTP and HTTP comes with the concept of using cookies. Those cookies are often forgotten when people talk about REST API and workflows and interactions spanning multiple resources or requests.

Remember what is written in the Wikipedia about HTTP cookies:

> Cookies were designed to be a reliable mechanism for websites to remember stateful information (such as items in a shopping cart) or to record the user's browsing activity (including clicking particular buttons, logging in, or recording which pages were visited by the user as far back as months or years ago).

So basically if you need to pass on state, use a cookie. It is designed for exactly the very same reason, it is HTTP and therefore it is compatible to REST by design :).

---

The better solution:

If you talk about a client performing a workflow involving multiple requests you usually talk about protocol. Every form of protocol comes with a set of preconditions for each potential step like perform step A before you can do B.

This is natural but exposing protocol to clients makes everything more complex. In order to avoid it just think what we do when we have to do complex interactions and things in the real world... . We use an Agent.

Using the Agent metaphor you can provide a resource that can perform all necessary steps for you and store the actual assignment / instructions it is acting upon in its list (so we can use POST on the agent or an 'agency').

A complex example:

Buying a house:

You need to prove your credibility (like providing your police record entries), you need to ensure financial details, you need to buy the actual house using a lawyer and a trusted third party storing the funds, verify that the house now belongs to you and add the buying stuff to your tax records etc. (just as an example, some steps may be wrong or whatever).

These steps might take several days to be completed, some can be done in parallel etc.

In order to do this, you just give the agent the task buy house like:

```
POST: agency.com/ { task: "buy house", target:"link:toHouse", credibilities:"IamMe"}.
```

Done. The agency sends you back a reference to you that you can use to see and track the status of this job and the rest is done automatically by the agents of the agency.

Think about a bug tracker for instance. Basically you report the bug and can use the bug id to check whats going on. You can even use a service to listen to changes of this resource. Mission Done.

Answer (score 2):

You must not use server side transactions in REST.

One of the REST contraints:

> Stateless
>
> The client–server communication is further constrained by no client context being stored on the server between requests. Each request from any client contains all of the information necessary to service the request, and any session state is held in the client.

The only RESTful way is to create a transaction redo log and put it into the client state. With the requests the client sends the redo log and the server redoes the transaction and

1. rolls the transaction back but provides a new transaction redo log (one step further)
2. or finally complete the transaction.

But maybe it's simpler to use a server session based technology which supports server side transactions.

Comment: The quote is from the wikipedia REST entry. Is this the real source or did wikipedia get it from somewhere? Who's to say what's client context and what's server context?

Answer (score 1):

I think that in this case it is totally acceptable to break the pure theory of REST in this situation. In any case, I don't think there is anything actually in REST that says you can't touch dependent objects in business cases that require it.

I really think it's not worth the extra hoops you would jump through to create a custom transaction manager, when you could just leverage the database to do it.

Comment: then it's just a normal web call, rpc or name it what you want, but it isn't REST

Comment: @bebbo ... 13 years later my answer has more nuance. If you need transactions, your view of REST is probably coupled to the database structure and you have a leaky abstraction. The Resource in this case is the transfer and it should encompass all of the information required to create the resource.

Answer (score 1):

In the simple case (without distributed resources), you could consider the transaction as a resource, where the act of creating it attains the end objective.

So, to transfer between `<url-base>/account/a` and `<url-base>/account/b`, you could post the following to `<url-base>/transfer`.

```
<transfer>
    <from><url-base>/account/a</from>
    <to><url-base>/account/b</to>
    <amount>50</amount>
</transfer>
```

This would create a new transfer resource and return the new url of the transfer - for example `<url-base>/transfer/256`.

At the moment of successful post, then, the 'real' transaction is carried out on the server, and the amount removed from one account and added to another.

This, however, doesn't cover a distributed transaction (if, say 'a' is held at one bank behind one service, and 'b' is held at another bank behind another service) - other than to say "try to phrase all operations in ways that don't require distributed transactions".

Comment: If you can't "phrase all operations in ways that don't require distributed transactions", then you really do need a two phase commit. The best idea I could find for implementing two phase commit on REST is http://rest.blueoxen.net/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?TwoPhaseCommit, which importantly doesn't mess up the URL namespace and allows a two phase commit to be layered over clean REST semantics.

Comment: The other problem with this suggestion is that, if a cache hiccups and POSTs twice, you get two transfers.

Comment: True, in which case you'd need to have a two step process - create a "transfer" resource with a unique URL then add the transfer details to it as part of the commit (two parts as mentioned in the other answers).  Of course, this could then be phrased as creating a "transaction" resource then adding a "transfer" operation to it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that would be the case of using a unique identifier generated on the client to ensure that the connection hiccup not imply in an duplicity saved by the API.

I think using a client generated GUID field along with the transfer object and ensuring that the same GUID was not reinserted again would be a simpler solution to the bank transfer matter.

Do not know about more complex scenarios, such as multiple airline ticket booking or micro architectures.

I found a paper about the subject, relating the experiences of [dealing with the transaction atomicity in RESTful services](http://ws-rest.org/2014/sites/default/files/wsrest2014_submission_7.pdf).

Answer (score -4):

I guess you could include the TAN in the URL/resource:

1. PUT /transaction to get the ID (e.g. "1")
2. [PUT, GET, POST, whatever] /1/account/bob
3. [PUT, GET, POST, whatever] /1/account/bill
4. DELETE /transaction with ID 1

Just an idea.

Comment: I see two problems with this approach:

1) It implies you can't access a resource outside a transaction (though maybe this isn't a big deal).
2) None of the answers so far has touched upon the fact that the server is no longer stateless, though I suspect nothing can be done about that.

Comment: Well, /1/account/bob and /account/bob are just two different resources. :) And RE: stateless, it implies that the resource is always available and not dependent on a previous request. Since you asked for transactions, yes that is not the case. But then again, you wanted transactions.

Comment: If a client has to assemble URIs, then your API is not RESTful.

Comment: I can't understand you guys, really! If you treat a transaction as a resource (like in the example above) you simply stop treating transaction in the classical sense and utilize it in "the proper REST way" which further simplifies programming transactional processes. You can for example include an href to the transaction in your responses to go around the displacement in distributed server-side environment, it's still stateless (it's just a resource, isn't it?) and you can implement the actual transaction mechanism anyway you want (what if you don't have a DB in the back?)

Comment: One way or the other if you simply stop thinking SQL/SOAP and start thinking HTTP (like the browser does) everything becomes simple