# REST API : write only resource. What to send back?

Tags: api, rest, web

basically, I want to POST a resource C to the server.
Depending on cases, the creation of a resource C may create resources A and B too.
As relationship matters, C is nested in B, himself nested in A.

In that case, we need to POST more data than just the resource C, hence, we'll be POSTing a write only resource, D, that doesn't have any meaning expect in this case.

My question is : What shall my api send back ? 200 Okay, 201 Created ? Shall I send the created resource C ?

Thanks.

Comment: Giving a real life example could make it easier to understand the question.

Comment: I wish this question to stay as theoretical as possible, thus avoiding real example.

If I am unclear, I'll do my best to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should return `201` whenever you want to tell user the action succeeded and as a result an entity was created.

The newly created recrod should be included as well.

I'm writing this based mostly on the [Rest API tutorial](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html).

Comment: The thing is : I'm asked to create D, and I answer with C, isn't it a bit strange ?

Comment: I find strange that you have one URL and based on content you create 2 different entities. I would say you should have two different request. One for creating C only (which fails if the parent doesn't exist) and one for creating D. It sounds like you know on the client which is the case (you are sending different parameters). So I would split it. It's hard to tell though when there is no real life example.

Comment: This all sounds like url "/createCorDTogetherWithCBasedOnWhatIsInTheRequest". In my understanding you should have split url for creating the separate resources

Comment: D is more like C with more infos to either find which B this C should refer to or create A, B and C.

Comment: It's hard to tell more, but in such case I would expect separate requests. To create C under particular B it would be like POST /C/{idOfC}/B, if you need to create C first do 2 steps: POST /C and then based in what C returns POST /C/{idOfC}/B etc.

Comment: Oh, isn't this what you are really concerned about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147207/transactions-in-rest

Comment: On the API caller side, I don't know B id. On server side, an algorithm will run to find if this C relates to an already existing B or not.

Comment: Since the difference between D and C is kept in A and B for storages matter, what about POSTing C nested in a (very) partial B and a (quite much) partial A ? Hence I would make a POST on A. Would it be REST ?