# What response code should I use on a REST API with multiple steps?

Tags: rest, api, http, multi-step

I'm working on a REST API that requires multiple steps/validations to create a resource, then making a `POST /transfer` might not create an actual transfer resource (because it needs an extra steps), but is not failing as it will trigger the second step/validation.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8499518/337772) the response is an incomplete or pending transaction with an id, and the resource includes endpoints to finish the transaction, like `/transaction/123/commit` or in my case `/transaction/123/verification/432` where the client can continue, abort or finish the transaction processing.

But what are the possible response codes on that endpoints? Does `/transaction/123/commit` actually returns **201** because it create the transaction or the transaction is created when it reach `pending` state?

Comment: Are you not able to ask for all the information up front?  Could the first POST create a "request" document and return the "request" ID and a second call could begin the processing of the request?

Comment: No, I can't ask all the information upfront, because some validations are challenges generated with data from the first request.

Comment: I thought about being hiding other resource, and thought about which name it could have, but I don't see that adding a `request` resource could help here. Something like `transaction_draft` maybe?

Comment: Neither HTTP nor REST support a multi-step resource creation process OOTB. You can either create intermediary resources similar to GIT commits which depict a transactional view and allow a rollback later on or you have a unique resource which you update (Patch/Put) later on with the new information sent by the client. If the client is interessted in the current state return a 200 OK with the current body else a 201 Created for the initial resource and a 202 Accepted for the remaining parts. Note further that REST cares only for the state of the resource but not the transaction actually.

Answer (score 1):

### 201 (Created)

Status code [201 (Created)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.2) indicates the creation of (at least one) new **HTTP resource**. The URL of the created resource is sent in the response’s `Location` header.

If `POST /transfer` creates the resource `/transaction/123/commit` — that is, if requests to `/transaction/123/commit` might now succeed where previously you’d have 404 (Not Found) — then it is correct to respond to `POST /transfer` with 201 and `Location: /transaction/123/commit`.

If `POST /transfer` creates several resources, then `Location` must be the “primary” one (in some sense).

If `POST /transaction/123/commit` does not create any new resource, then it is incorrect to respond with 201, even if it does create something else (like an internal database record).

If you can’t come up with a URL to send in `Location`, that probably means you’re not creating any new resource, in which case 201 is incorrect.

Note: `Location` is always relative to the request URL, not to an “API root” or any such concept you might have. For example, if `POST /api/v1/foo/bar` creates `/api/v1/foo/bar/baz`, correct values for `Location` would include `bar/baz` and `/api/v1/foo/bar/baz`, but not `/foo/bar/baz`.

### 200 (OK)

Status code [200 (OK)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) indicates general success. It can be used in most successful responses. It’s a kind of a safe fallback: it doesn’t say much, thus it’s guaranteed not to say much *wrong* and confuse the client.

If `POST /transaction/123/commit` succeeds without creating a new resource, then it is correct to respond with 200.

### 204 (No Content)

Except for responses to `GET`/`HEAD`, status code [204 (No Content)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5) is mostly the same as 200. If you use 204 to say something different than 200, you’re probably making up a local convention — same as making up your own status code 275.

### Other

IANA maintains a [registry of standardized status codes](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml). You can look there for a status code that is standardized to mean exactly what you want to say.

You generally don’t want to use a non-standard status code, or to use a standard status code *incorrectly*, because that would preclude a [uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5), which is kind of the whole point of REST.

If you find yourself struggling all the time to uphold a uniform interface, it’s possible that you don’t need REST at all, and should be doing RPC instead.